# How to update this package for new version

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to make this package usable again.
But this thing is so old that I can't use it anymore.
Can someone help and fix it for me?
I really need this thing.
Please help me .
And I want to use it as an example.

Package link  :
https://github.com/csnewman/flutter_logicblocks.git

Answer (score 0):

To update a package for a new version,
You can Fork the repository & update the deprecated codebase.

#### Follow these steps to update the package:

- **Fork the Repository:**
  Go to the GitHub repository link & click on the **"Fork"** button at the top-right corner to create a copy of the repository under your GitHub account.
- **Clone the Forked Repository:**
  Open a terminal or command prompt on your local machine & clone the forked repository to your computer.
- **Update the Code:**
  Make the necessary changes to the package's codebase to bring it up to date.
  Update dependencies if required.
  *(**Note:** Install Flutter extensions in your development environment, it can be helpful for identifying deprecated code and getting suggestions on how to update it)*
- **Use updated forked package:**
  Now import your forked package as a new package into your Flutter project.
  *(You can also generate PR request for contribute to others developers)*

Add dependency in **pubspec.yaml** file & run the command: `flutter pub get`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  your_forked_package:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/your-github-username/flutter_logicblocks.git
```

#### Alternate way:

You can also use the codebase of others who have previously forked the package.
[Click here to see available Forkes](https://github.com/csnewman/flutter_logicblocks/forks?include=active%2Carchived%2Cinactive%2Cnetwork&page=1&period=&sort_by=stargazer_counts).

Also, you can choose from the option:
[image: Forks]